# Why isn't Python writing elements from one 3-D list to another?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a program that creates an average out of an image by looping through each RGBA value in two images to average them out and create one composite image, but the right value isn't being written to my list comp_img, which contains all the new image data.

I'm using these 256x256 images for debugging.
[image: Text] [image: Text]

But it just creates this as output:

[image: Text]

While this is the composite color, the 64 gets wiped out entirely. Help is very much appreciated, thank you.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from math import ceil
from time import sleep

red = Image.open("64red.png")
grn = Image.open("64green.png")
comp_img = []

temp = [0,0,0,0] #temp list used for appending
#temp is a blank pixel template
for i in range(red.width):
    comp_img.append(temp)
    
temp = comp_img
#temp should now be a row template composed of pixel templates
#2d to 3d array code go here
comp_img = []
for i in range(red.height):
    comp_img.append(temp)

reddata = np.asarray(red)
grndata = np.asarray(grn)

reddata = reddata.tolist() #its uncanny how easy it is
grndata = grndata.tolist()

for row, elm in enumerate(reddata):
    for pxl, subelm in enumerate(elm):
        for vlu_index, vlu in enumerate(subelm):
            comp_img[row][pxl][vlu_index] = ceil((reddata[row][pxl][vlu_index] + grndata[row][pxl][vlu_index])/2)
            #These print statements dramatically slowdown the otherwise remarkably quick program, and are solely for debugging/demonstration.
            


output = np.array(comp_img, dtype=np.uint8) #the ostensible troublemaker
outputImg = Image.fromarray(output)
outputImg.save("output.png")
```

Comment: Not quite sure what all those nested for-loops are doing but is that really the best approach to convert a numpy array to list in order to run nested for-loops? No way to vectorize?

Comment: Have you tried to simplify the problem by doing the same exercise with a pair of grayscale images?

Comment: The for loops are supposed to open each row of pixels in the image, then each pixel in the rows, and finally each individual RGBA value. The innermost loop is supposed to calculate the average and write it to comp_img in the same spot.

Comment: Just don't convert arrays to lists, try vectorized instead: `comp_img = np.ceil(np.mean(np.array([reddata, grndata]), axis=0))`

Comment: did you try to do simply `(red + grn) / 2` or `(reddata + grndata) / 2` ? I think `Pillow` or `numpy` should do this whithout `for`-loops.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do

```
comp_img = np.ceil((reddata + grndata) / 2)
```

This gives me

[image]

To get correct values it needs to work with `16bit` values - because for `uint8` it works only with values `0..255` and `255+255` gives `254` instead of `510` (it calculates it `modulo 256` and `(255+255) % 256` gives `254`)

```
reddata = np.asarray(red, dtype=np.uint16)
grndata = np.asarray(grn, dtype=np.uint16)
```

and then it gives

[image]

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

red = Image.open("64red.png")
grn = Image.open("64green.png")

reddata = np.asarray(red, dtype=np.uint16)
grndata = np.asarray(grn, dtype=np.uint16)

#print(reddata[128,128])
#print(grndata[128,128])

#comp_img = (reddata + grndata) // 2
comp_img = np.ceil((reddata + grndata) / 2)

#print(comp_img[128,128])

output = np.array(comp_img, dtype=np.uint8)
outputImg = Image.fromarray(output)
outputImg.save("output.png")
```

Comment: There's a slight oversight that's causing it to become gray. The UInt8 RGB values of white is (255,255,255). Adding those causes an overflow to (254,254,254). Then dividing by 2 goes to (127,127,127), which is gray.

Comment: @BatWannaBe I aready added information that it has to convert to `np.uint16`

Answer (score 1):

You really should work with just NumPy arrays and functions, but I'll explain the bug here. It's rooted in how you make the nested list. Let's look at the first level:

```
temp = [0,0,0,0] #temp list used for appending
#temp is a blank pixel template
for i in range(red.width):
    comp_img.append(temp)
```

At this stage, `comp_img` is a list with size `red.width` whose every element/pixel references the *same* RGBA-list `[0,0,0,0]`. I don't just mean the values are the same, it's *one* RGBA-list object. When you edit the values of that one RGBA-list, you edit all the pixels' colors at once.

Just fixing that step isn't enough. You also make the same error in the next step of expanding `comp_img` to a 2D matrix of RGBA-lists; every row is the same list.

If you really want to make a blank `comp_img` first, you should just make a NumPy array of a numerical scalar dtype; there you can guarantee every element is independent:

```
comp_img = np.zeros((red.height, red.width, 4), dtype = np.uint8)
```

If you really want a nested list, you have to properly instantiate (make new) lists at every level for them to be independent. A list comprehension is easy to write:

```
comp_img = [[[0,0,0,0] for i in range(red.width)] for j in range(red.height)]
```